# Trying to set value inside a textbox in gridview header

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to set the value of a textbox inside the header template of a grid view but not able to do.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" 
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="ABC">
<HeaderTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="d1" runat="server">ABC</asp:TextBox></HeaderTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.cs side
trying to set value

```
gv.HeaderRow.FindControl("d1"). ="DEF"
```

Expected:textbox with Id="d1" should be set as DEF
Actual:Not getting appropriate syntax to bind it after this code gv.HeaderRow.FindControl("d1").

Comment: You probably want it more like 

var control = (Textbox)gv.HeaderRow.FindControl("d1);
control.Text = "DEF";

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Text` of textbox after gridview binded. Below code sets text value of textbox

```
gv.DataSource = list;
gv.DataBind();
((TextBox)gv.HeaderRow.FindControl("d1")).Text = "DEF";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by adding `onRowDataBound` event to your grid and write the following code `server side`

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{          
 TextBox txtd1= (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("d1");     
 txtd1.Text="your text";
}
```